# How to export audio file in app for iOS?

Tags: ios, audio

We can use both UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum and UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum save Image or Video to photo album for iOS, then how to save audio? If value is NO for key with application supports iTunes file share, whether has other ways to do?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are going to share audio file with the user. iTunes File sharing is the option to go, but if you don't want to enable that, you can upload file to some service(cloud, social network, etc), and give the link to file to the user. Other ways to share would be using Bluetooth (which can be used only with iOS devices), through Bonjour services?, or you could also share the file over local wifi network by running web server in your app. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Audio Files cannot be saved to the camera roll, but you can save them in your apps Documents folder. From there you can play files you create. You can also play files from the media library (that's what the iPod/Music function does).

I've explained in more detail how to save an audio file that was recorded with your device here: http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-record-audio-from-the-microphone-in-ios/

I guess to answer your question better we need to know where your audio came from.